# How to make a banner position change on click on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is this --
I've created a top bar banner on a website that pulls down nicely via :hover on desktop. On mobile the banner pulls down when you click on it - and it floats back up if you click off on the page, anywhere other than the banner. I need the banner to disappear back up when you click on it again instead of having to click on page to make it go away.

This is my current css:

```
    aside.banner-container {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
background: #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
position: absolute;
top: -135px;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0px auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
-webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
-moz-transition: top 1s ease;
transition: top 1s ease;
z-index: 999;
    }
    .banner-container:hover, .banner-container:focus, .banner-container:active {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
  }
```

JSP page if that makes a difference. Researching I can see onClick events in Javascript, but if I tell the positioning to be "top: -135px" onClick won't that mess with the initial click that needs to happen for the banner to pull down in the first place on mobile? Or no because that's from hover technically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.banner');
elem.onclick = function(){
 if ( elem.classList.contains('clicked') ) 
  {
   elem.setAttribute('class','banner');
   elem.style.top = '-260px';
  }
 else 
  {
   elem.setAttribute('class','banner clicked');
   elem.style.top = '0';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.400s;
}
body,html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.banner-ct {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: -260px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
}
.banner p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-ct">
  <div class="banner">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is example of js onclick function. 
Notice that forcing "click" in JS won't work. Mobile devices secure settings :).